# Modifying a pseudo element and wilcard selecting

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if it's possible to modify a wild card element which also has a pseudo element style. I'm trying to remove an annoying bit of padding but I'm not having much luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the rendered HTML.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div id="parent-1">
            ::before
            <div id="child-1">
                <a class="link">
                    <img src="/picture.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hint">
                        <span class="hint-message">Hint Text</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            ::after
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div id="parent-2">
            ::before
            <div id="child-2">
                <a class="link">
                    <img src="/picture.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hint">
                        <span class="hint-message">Hint Text</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            ::after
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to modify the ":after" css pseudo element which is proving to be a little challenging.. not even sure if it's technically possible since it's not a real element?

Here is what I have tried so far

```
div[id^="child-"]:after{ padding:0px !important;}
```

also tried this

```
#child-*:after{ padding:0px !important;}
```

and this

```
:after { padding:0px !important;}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle with this? i guess it should work, while pseudos are not DOM elements, that means that you can't get them programmatically with the DOM functions or modify them, but with styles (even creating them dynamically) i never had a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div[id^="child-"]:after{ padding:0px !important;}
```

This works for me. I created a [demo here](http://codepen.io/suinanli/pen/gMpxge).
I think the "annoying padding" is caused by other reasons. Could you provide the css?

Comment: Thank you, you were correct it was being caused by another style rule further down in the CSS. Glad to know that I wasn't going insane and my first thought was correct.